# How does Mono for Android work?

Tags: android, mono, dalvik, xamarin.android

I am interested in how Mono for Android (by Novell) works.

My biggest question is around the actual runtime's that are used.  Is MfA providing a Mono runtime that wraps and calls down to the Dalvik runtime or is the Dalvik completely bypassed in this operation?  Is it something else completely?

I am curious because I hear that the Mono runtime has better performance on mobile devices (not that I believe anything I read on the internet...), and really I am just trying to understand the whole thing.

Any other general knowledge on the topic of comparing and contrasting Mono/Dalvik runtimes would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's both! Some things are run directly in Mono on the kernel and some things get passed into the Dalvik system.

http://mono-android.net/Documentation/Architecture

Comment: +1 Excellent answer.  I was looking for exactly that.  Do not know how I missed it before, as I went through most of those pages already!

Answer (score 0):

Link to site provided by @trutheality is already dead.

Newest version of Mono for Android would be found here: https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/mono_for_android_4/mono_for_android_4.4/

It's seems to be a bit out-of-dated version as it has support for earlier Jelly Bean Android version. Nowadays, `MonoDroid` is called `Xamarin.Android` and now it's in 6.0.1 version.

but there are no official information how compatible is it with MonoDevelop IDE or how it works on Linux.

I sent today a message about it to Xamarin. Hope they would explain me clearly how it nowadays looks like.